# Hide microphone button Android virtual keyboard

Tags: android

I wanted to know if is it possible to hide the microphone button (speech-to-text) in Android Virtual Keyboard programatically.

I know I can disable this option through device settings, but I don't want the user to use this feature in my application independently of his/her settings. 
I mean i want to force this behaviour inside my app.

Thanks in advance,
Demian

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't force the user input through anything other than pre-defined keyboards that already exist in the user's device.

The only way you could get around this is by programming your own custom, on-the-fly keyboard, and that is a very bad idea.

Just disable voice input programmatically by using XML declarations in the EditText you're looking at.  You can do this with the attribute:

```
android:privateImeOptions="nm"
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. Now I can't find any tag to disable voice input in EditField, could you pass me the tag, please?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#inputType  Take a look through here and see if you can find what you're looking for.  Each phone may be different, but you might find a "set" for what you want.

Answer (score 25):

Here's how you do it: android:privateImeOptions="nm" - nm stands for No Microphone.

Comment: Thanks, this does work for EditText. However, I have not been able to disable the microphone key on keyboard for SearchView. Looking at the source code, it does not seem possible.. any ideas for achieving it for SearchView?

Comment: @markostamcar, In my case microphone is not visible, what could be done to show the microphone?

Comment: Whilst I cannot recommend it, for SearchView you'll need to call this method on searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text) which is the actual AutoCompleteTextView.